# Distribute joints on procedural pipes with geo nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, procedural

I'm trying to make a procedural pipe generator with geo nodes, the thing is that I have no idea how to distribute the joints where I want. The pipes work by extruding vertices. Here is an example:
[image: Pipes skeleton]
[image: Pipes]
[image: Geo nodes of that]

But when adding joints, I have no idea how to control where to place them. I want them to be place automatically in sections like this:

[image: Where I want them]

Following this image as reference:

[image: Image reference]

Edit: Currently, I manage to slide them where I want, I just need to find a way to make the ones on each end of the pipe to not translate:
[image: Pipes]

Here is how I did it:
[image]

But I'm not sure yet how to isolate the ones at the end of each pipe as they are now seen as individual edges, not conected between them. Any ideas?

Either way I'll say that's not really important now, I thing it works pretty well as how it is right now:
[image: edit mode]
[image: procedural pipes]
[image: With Material]

Comment: search for johnny matthews on yt. He made a great tutorial about it.

Comment: This might be the video @Chris was referring to: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_qOLhZQM_7c

Comment: Thank you guys, unfortunatly, some nodes aren't aviable any more on Blender 4.x

Comment: From your picture with the red lines, I would propose to define a distance from the "central" node of the device (bend, T-junction, ...)  to place joints (plus one at each end obviously). Or to add boxes centred on devices and to put joints at intersection with the segments. How much control would you like ? How automatic would you like it ? Could you use vertex weight to encode this distance ? Could you use vertex groups per kind of devices to hard-code these distances in GN graph ?

Comment: I want to make it a automatically as possible. I found a different approach but I still need help. I'm going to edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Using Blender 3.6.8)*

Making assumptions about some not shown parts of your GN graph, here is a proposal where new nodes are highlighted in green, and modified nodes in orange.
Before splitting edges to make disconnected curves, the number of edges connected to each vertex is recovered by an *Edges of Vertex* node to be stored as an attribute in *Point* domain. Free end vertices have a count of 1 ; others have a count of 2 or more. This attribute is firstly transmitted to curve control points through the *Mesh to Curve* node, then to spawned instances through the *Instance on Points* nodes. It is finally used as a selection mask for the *Translate Instances* nodes, to shift only joints with at least 2 connections.

[image: Pipes with joints]

[image: GN graph]

Resources: [image]

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfectly!